# Solr: Does the PatternReplaceFilterFactory able to replace the field value for copyField and then index it?

Tags: search, solr, solr4

I have indexed the data from solr.xml and monitor.xml that came with the solr package, and I added the below configuration in the schema.xml file

```
<field name="my_field" type="my_field_type" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="my_field" />
<fieldType name="my_field_type" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern=".*" replacement="NameChanged" replace="all" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

It copies the (name) field to (my_field) of the fieldType (my_field_type). In the (my_field_type), I used PatternReplaceFilterFactory trying to replace everything with the string "NameChanged". The result is that it did copy the (name) field and its value to (my_field), but the value still stays the same.For example the below returned results with the (name) and (my_field) fields, the values of those two fields are the same, it didn't change the value to "NameChanged" for the field (my_field)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">2</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="fl">id,name,my_field,</str>
    <str name="indent">true</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="_">1380593840070</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">SOLR1000</str>
    <str name="name">Solr, the Enterprise Search Server</str>
    <str name="my_field">Solr, the Enterprise Search Server</str></doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">3007WFP</str>
    <str name="name">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</str>
    <str name="my_field">Dell Widescreen UltraSharp 3007WFP</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

So, does the PatternReplaceFilterFactory able to replace the field value for copyField and then index it? If yes, what did I do wrong in the above configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer chain is for **tokenized** (searchable) representation of the field. The result you are showing is for original **stored** representation. That's why you will not see any changes that way.

Instead, check the tokenized representation in Admin interface either in field analyzer screen or in schema description field (one with checkmark to load tokens). Or, for a quick test, use **my_field** as a facet, as facet uses the actual tokens.

If you are trying to change the actual stored representation, as well as indexed one, you are better off with UpdateRequestProcessor chain using [CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) and [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html). That's defined in solrconfig.xml and applies on the document before it is stored/indexed at all.

Comment: Thanks. It did show the change when I do the facet on my_field. When I search for my_field:namedchanged but it didn't find anything, do you know why? I am trying to copy a field, change its value and be able to search the new value.

Comment: In the (Solr 4+) admin interface, you have a screen where you can put the same phrase on the left and right side and they go through indexing and query chain correspondingly. And show the final tokens. This allows you to understand the consequences of your chain configuration. E.g. misspellings (like in your own example 'namechanged' vs. 'namedchanged')

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask you some more questions? If I put bq=my_field:namechanged^100.00 in the query, will it boost the score for document with "namedchanged" in the my_field value? If I put 20 of those bq parameters in the query, will it affects the search performance?

Comment: I need to mask sensitive data in solr search result, how could i do such a thing?