# Solr - PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory does not index regexp result

Tags: filter, solr

I am using Solr 7. I have a field "date" of type "pdate" that contains a date such as 
`2019-01-24T14:43:13Z`.

```
<field name="date" type="pdate" stored="true"/>
```

I want from this date to index in a "hour" field the value `14:43:13`.
To do that, I created a new field

```
<field name="hour" type="parsed_hour" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I used a copyfield to put in "hour" the value of my "date"

```
<copyField source="date" dest="hour"/>
```

and setup a PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory, to make sure that "hour" contains only the hour digits of the "date" value.

```
<fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true"/>
<fieldType name="parsed_hour" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" pattern="(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})" preserve_original="false"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I did try the regex and it is capturing the right group:

https://regex101.com/r/r7Id29/1

But as a result, after indexing I see that my "hour" field is just an exact copy of my "date field", without any modifcation.
I expected "hour" to have a value of "14:43:13".

Also if I test using the Analysis in Solr Admin UI, I see that my date is properly parsed by the PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory to output my hour.

[image]

The problem is the result of the PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory is just not pushed to the "hour" field...

[image]

Comment: I just found more explanation on why it's not working the way I thought at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19128753/2299336

Comment: You can use [an update chain with an update processor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) that handles the regex instead: [RegexReplaceProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/RegexReplaceProcessorFactory.html)